# create procedure function as alternative to DB timeout

Tags: mysql-workbench, sql-procedure

So I am fairly new to sql and there is a particular query I make where the DB always timeout. I tried everything, including restarting the server.

There is this table where it listed all the events happening in an app, together with the person_role and the platform version it happened. So an example columnns and rows would be:

platform_id | aggregate_id | job_id | creator_id | event_type | timestamp | client | role | app_version|

so for example if I want to just check all the events associated with a particular job_id Ill just use a WHERE statement.
Also take note that when I query other tables, there is no timeout, just this particular table.

I tried asking around and somebody recommended a stored procedure function to make the query faster. I tried it and actually it is just an empty table. Any other suggestions?

This is the simple query :
SELECT * FROM db.events
WHERE job_id = '1234566677'

To know all the events associated with that particular job_id.

Comment: It would help if you provided a schema, sample data and a sample query that timesout

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does your table have any indexes and what are they? What does the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` say when you run this query?

Comment: hello yes. So I run Explain analyze on a simple Select * query and this is `-> Limit: 10 row(s)  (cost=106631881.96 rows=10) (actual time=0.060..0.064 rows=10 loops=1)
    -> Table scan on event_role  (cost=106631881.96 rows=941448796) (actual time=0.059..0.062 rows=10 loops=1)` I have to limit to 10 otherwise it would time out again!